# What muscles am I using when wheeling?

Tags: mountain-bike, training, fitness, tricks

I recently received a MTB as a birthday gift. I'm 18 now but have been riding bikes since I was 6. I've always wanted to wheelie for longer distances and now I learned how to after praying. But anyway, I'd like to improve by training my muscles, but I don't know what muscles I have to stress in order to get better wheelie endurance. I have a back hydraulic suspension which I set to bet pretty hard because the softer it is the more of a setback it is for wheeling.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSqkKtnMM_U&t=0m57s)?

Comment: I suspect developing physical maturity had a big effect on your coordination and ability to wheelie.

Comment: @andy256 yes, that's exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: @Criggie not really… I had a dream after praying in which I did a 2 minute wheelie. The next day I could wheelie for much longer than before.

Comment: To which deity did you pray? Is there a special supernatural being for wheelies, or can you get awesome wheelie power from a generic big brand god or godess?

Comment: @stib prayed to the Creator, YHWH the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. But that's not the point… can you answer my question?

Comment: Wow. Of all the things in the world YHWH could have intervened in, he chose to give you Wheelie Powers. Hey next time could you pray for world peace or an end to hunger while you're at it? Since He's obviously listening to you…

Comment: @stib don't tell me you're an atheist…

Comment: No, I worship Jens Voigt.

Comment: Never done a wheelie for more than about 0.5 second, but it's really more of a matter of balance and control than raw strength, once you're "up".  I suspect that if you do a wheelie for a couple of minutes you will find that an hour later your entire body hurts -- you were using *everything*.

Answer (score 6):

Wheelies aren't a strength thing, they are a function of weight distribution on the bike.

If you move your weight far enough back the front wheel will lift - this can initially be assisted by applying a few hard pedal strokes in a light gear.  As you correctly observed, rear suspension is a disadvantage here, as it absorbs some of your initial weight movement.
Once the front wheel is up its about maintaining your balance point.

As with anything balance related, some core strength conditioning will help, but is not really much of a determining factor in ability to wheelie for long durations.